# Java не получается послать Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-broadcastreceiver

Я пытаюсь передать Intent из сервиса в MainActivity в BroadcastReciver, но либо интент не передается, либо BroadcastReciver его не принимает. Ниже код Activity где я должен получать intent

```
    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

public final static String PARAM_SRVRESP = "srvresp";

public final static String PARAM_GTOKEN = "task";
BroadcastReceiver br;

public final static String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.catsoftdevelopment.servicetest";
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    bindService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyTestService.class), sConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "BroadCast Reciever created");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    br = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String gtoken = intent.getStringExtra(PARAM_GTOKEN);
            String srvresp = intent.getStringExtra(PARAM_SRVRESP);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onReceive: srvresp = " + srvresp + ", gtoken = " + gtoken);
            if (intent.getAction()==Intent.ACTION_MAIN){
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onReceive: srvresp = " + srvresp + ", gtoken = " + gtoken);
            }
        }
    };

    IntentFilter intFilt = new IntentFilter(BROADCAST_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(br, intFilt);

}
protected void onDestroy() {
    unbindService(sConn);
    super.onDestroy();
}
boolean bound = false;
MyTestService myTestService;
ServiceConnection sConn = new ServiceConnection() {

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MainActivity onServiceConnected");
        MyTestService.MyTestBinder mybinder = (MyTestService.MyTestBinder) binder;
        myTestService = mybinder.getService();
        bound = true;
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MainActivity onServiceDisconnected");
        bound = false;
    }
};
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
    }
```

Service откуда я передаю intent

```
public class FcmTokenRegistrationService extends IntentService {

public FcmTokenRegistrationService() {
    super("FcmTokenRegistrationService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {

                        Logg.d("Firebase getInstanceId failed " + task.getException());
                        return;
                    }

                    // Get new Instance ID token
                    String token = task.getResult().getToken();
                   //MainActivity.GetNewGtoken(token);
                    Logg.d("Firebase registrationToken=" + token);
                    Intent gtokintent; = new Intent();
                  gtokintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    gtokintent.putExtra(MainActivity.PARAM_GTOKEN, token);
                    sendBroadcast(gtokintent);
                }
            });
}
}
```

Если шагать в дебаге эти строки почему-то не выполняются

```
   Intent gtokintent; = new Intent();
   gtokintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
   gtokintent.putExtra(MainActivity.PARAM_GTOKEN, token);
```

со строки `Logg.d("Firebase registrationToken=" + token);` 
сразу перепрыгивает на `sendBroadcast(gtokintent);`

Comment: Что за точка запитая при объявлении gtokintent?

Comment: опечатка при редактировании когда выкладыва сюда, в коде Intent gtokintent = new Intent();

Comment: Попробуйте унаследовать просто `Service` вместо `IntentService`

Comment: Ресивер регистрируете с фильтром на `BROADCAST_ACTION`, а посылаете `Intent.ACTION_MAIN`. Вообще в пределах своего приложения бродкасты лучше отправлять и регистрировать через [`LocalBroadcastManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/localbroadcastmanager/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html). Но и такой подход не оптимален  и объявлен устаревшим - обратите внимание на рекомендации в доках к классу.

Comment: Исправил, спасибо, но не помогло видимо осталосб от моих эксперементов с заменой ACTION

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему, проблема крылась в глюке AndroidStudio, переоткрыл студию, сделал Rebuild проекта и все пошло! Спасибо за комментарии